# How to Install Java (JDK/JRE) with PIP?

Tags: pip

How do I install a specific Jdk/JRE using pip?
I found [this](https://pypi.org/project/install-jdk/) link and the instruction is to run `pip install install-jdk`, however after I do that, where is Java?
If I run `java -version` nothing is returned.

Answer (score 4):

I dont know if it ispossible (install JAVA through PIP) my guess is it is not.
But what you have done with "*pip install install-jdk*" is just intalled a Python library called install-jdk. To have this working you need a python script that import this library and call the function who install JAVA. See https://pypi.org/project/install-jdk/

Answer (score 3):

it sounds like you haven't downloaded the official java yet.

you have to download java via their official website first https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/

afterwards, remember to set your PATH (under environment variables) to route to the correct java path

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking. I want to do it through pip, not manually.

Answer (score 3):

You have to read the docs completely. The pip package is not java itself, it is way cooler. It is a general java-installer. So after you pip-installed it, fire up python and do something like this:

```
import jdk

jdk.install('11', impl=jdk.Implementation.OPENJ9)
# Platform dependent install of Java JDK 11 with OpenJ9 into $HOME/.jdk/<VERSION>
```

etc. Then, the java package is being installed in `$HOME/.jdk/...`
Read the full documentation yourself. You posted the link in your question.

To enable a particular java version (or switch between them) you always do something like

```
export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/.jdk/myJavaVersion
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

in a highly system-dependent way. My example would fit a linux-bash environment. After you set the environment also `java --version` will do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution of  @Ralf Ulrich and it works for me. I tried it on kaggle.

1- first install `install-jdk` via `pip install install-jdk`

2- then run this code to install java-11 and add it to enviroment variable

```py
import jdk
from jdk.enums import OperatingSystem, Architecture

jdk.install('11', operating_system=OperatingSystem.LINUX)

import os
jdk_version = 'jdk-11.0.19+7' #change with your version 
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = '/root/.jdk/{jdk_version}'
os.environ['PATH'] = f"{os.environ.get('PATH')}:{os.environ.get('JAVA_HOME')}/bin"
```

After this it worked for me.